# create personal collections for logged in users

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

```
import {favRestaurants} from '/lib/collections';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {check} from 'meteor/check';

export default function () {
  Meteor.methods({
    'favRestaurants.create' (id, name, rating, priceLevel, type) {
      check(id, String);
      check(name, String);
      check(rating, Number);
      check(priceLevel, Number);
      check(type, String);
      const createdAt = new Date();
      const restaurant = {id, name, rating, priceLevel, type, createdAt};
      if(check(Meteor.user()) == null){
        console.log('onlye logged in users can data');
      }else{
        FavRestaurants.insert(restaurant);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is my insert method for adding data to the restaurants collections. When i console log the 'check(Meteor.user())' in the console i get null as output. By that logic you shouldn't be able to add data to the collection, although this is still possible.

I would also like to make the FavResaurants collection personal for each user. Iv'e tried to check if there is a user and then adding a collection in the main.js file on the client side.

```
Meteor.loggingIn(() => {
  console.log('check for user method');
  var restId = 0;
  if(Meteor.user() != null){
    console.log('created new collection for the user');
    const FavRestaurants = new Mongo.Collection('favRestaurants' + restId);
  }
  restId++;
});
```

I dont get any output to console using this method, which i found in the meteor [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html). Is the code in the wrong place? Any help is much appriciated.

According to the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Accounts-ui-config) the Accounts.ui.config is the method i should use. But I'm not sure in code i should put it. So far the placement of this method has resulted in my application crashing.

Comment: Collections need to be defined on both the client and server side except for *local collections* which are only defined on the client and never mapped back to the server.

Comment: the collection is defined on both client and server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question, to allow only logged-in clients to access a method, you should use something like:

```
if (!Meteor.userId()) {
   throw new Meteor.Error('403', 'Forbidden');
}
```

Now, I see you want a collection to store favorite restaurants for each user in client side. But as I see it, there'd be only one logged in user per client, so you don't need a separate collection for each user (as the collection is in each client), you can just refer the user with it's id, and then fetch a user's favorite restaurants by a query like:

```
FavRestaurants.find({user: Meteor.userId()});
```

Moreover, as the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn) suggest, `Meteor.loggingIn` is a method which tells you if some user is in the process of logging in. What you are doing is over-riding it, which doesn't make sense.

You should do something like:

```
if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
  // Do your stuff
}
```

Hope it gives you more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a collection per user is a bad approach.
Define your favRestaurants collection once and add a owner field in the restaurant document before insert.
Create a publish method to publish to client side the userid favrestaurant only.

One more thing, check your userid first in your Meteor method, it will avoid unnecessary proces.

Regs